# Type Definitions for Untyped Imports with Strict Compilation

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I'm getting errors when compiling my project with `--strict` while importing packages that lack type definitions. Even if I supply my own definitions, I still get an error.

Say I'm trying to use the package `untyped-lib`.

```
// index.js
import * as Untyped from 'untyped-lib';
```

I'll get the following error:

```
error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'untyped-lib'. '/Users/faraz/Workspace/project/node_modules/untyped-lib/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Now let's say I create a type definition for the file in `./mytypes/untyped-lib.d.ts`:

```
declare module "untyped-lib" {
  const typed: SomeInterface;
  export = typed; 
}
```

And add that directory to my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...,
        "typeRoots": [
            "./node_modules/@types",
            "./mytypes"
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm still getting the declaration issue. How can I supply the definition to TypeScript to make the error go away?

Comment: What are the contents of your `untyped-lib.d.ts` file?

Comment: I've added an example. I don't think TypeScript is picking up the directory I've added.